# How can I Join two tables using hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have a `OrderItem(order_id, product_id)`,  `Product(product_id, ...)` and `Order(order_id, ...)` tables. How can i use Criteria to get all products in a specific order ?

```
Criteria orderItemCriteria = session.createCriteria(OrderItem.class);
Criteria orderCriteria = orderItemCriteria.createAlias("order", "o");
orderCriteria = orderCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("o.id", orderId));
List<Product> orderProducts = orderItemCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("product")).list();
```

This gets all the `product_ids`. How can get all product details ?

**Note*** I'm getting `lazyInitializtionException` when trying to access any property of product except Id for sure and i don't need to change Fetching to EAGER.

Comment: As you seem to use the legacy criteria api, which version of Hibernate are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.3.1.Final

Comment: So you want a List<Product> of all products ordered in a particular orderId

Comment: No I need to retrieve the `product` as whole not just the `product_id`. I have tried your suggestion but it also throws `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` @Selaron

Comment: Yes, I ment to say a `List<Product>` filled with fully initialized entities of type `Product`.

Comment: Yes you're right? Any Suggestions?! @Selaron

Answer (score 0):

In case of the legacy `criteria` api you can use the `.setFetchMode("product", FetchMode.EAGER)` method: [See the 4.2 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-dynamicfetching).

In case of the JPA criteria API, you would use the `.fetch( OrderItem_.product )` method: [See the 5.4 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-from-fetch)

Comment: But I don't want to change fetching to EAGER I'm thinking If I could make another join between the `OrderItem` and `Product` tables so that I can get the whole product not just its Id.